# How to remove the % lines in xtable table output by Knitr

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

By using xtable and knitr, I add a table to my RMD document and export to PDF file.

`````
```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
xtable(matrixtable)
````
`````

It looks great except there is a line

```
% latex table generated in R 3.1.0 by xtable 1.7-3 package % Wed Jun 25 13:34:57 2014
```

How can I remove this line. I tried to set `message=FALSE` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The inclusion of the `comment` in the final table is defined by the comment argument to print.xtable

the default value for this is `getOption('xtable.comment',TRUE)`.

so, if you set

```
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
```

then for any future tables this comment will not produced.

Comment: important to distinguish that this approach will fix the issue _permanently_, while @Daniel's will do it case-by-case

Answer (score 30):

You can put in directly in the `print` statement like so:

```
xtb=xtable(...)
print(xtb, comment=FALSE)
```