# Hmisc latex fuction need to remove the first line

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

Im using Hmisc in rmarkdown file. when I create a table this is what I do

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r Arrests Stats, results ='asis', message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}

# render the table

options(digits=1)
library(Hmisc)
latex(head(mtcars), file="")

```
````

The latex output has the first row showing as below

```
%latex.default(cstats, title= title....
\begin{table}...
.
.
.
\end{tabular}
```

Notice the '%' I need to figure out to remove the first line as it shows on the PDF document when its weaved

Comment: I've done a test with `stargazer` too and there is a line of code with `%` as well. The very strange thing it that `%` is a comment for LaTeX and so with `asis` chunk option it should be ignored. Maybe it is a bug. Are you using knitr in Rstudio?

Comment: Anyway, there is a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400308/how-to-remove-the-lines-in-xtable-table-output-by-knitr) with `xtable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that's hard-coded into `latex.default` (`cat("%", deparse(sys.call()), "%\n", file = file, append = file != "", sep = "")` is in the body, with no conditional surrounding it).

I think your best guess then would be to `capture.output` the `cat`-d output and strip the comment yourself.

```
cat(capture.output(latex(head(mtcars), file=''))[-1], sep='\n')
```

The `capture.output` catches all the stuff that `latex(...)` `cat`s, the `[-1]` removes the first line (being the '%latex.default'), the `cat` prints out everything else, with newline separator.

You might define your own `mylatex` to do this, and be a little more clever (e.g. instead of blindly stripping the first line of the output, you could only strip it if it started with '%').

```
mylatex <- function (...) {
    o <- capture.output(latex(...))
    # this will strip /all/ line-only comments; or if you're only
    #  interested in stripping the first such comment you could
    #  adjust accordingly
    o <- grep('^%', o, inv=T, value=T)
    cat(o, sep='\n')
}
mylatex(head(mtcars), file='')
```